# How to sync frontend model with backend database

Tags: javascript, ajax

Take a "todo app" for example. As I add/remove items, or mark items as done, I want the frontend to automatically send ajax updates.

Also, if the backend were to change because somebody else added a new todo item, I want the frontend to update.

I know the `meteor` framework does this. Are there any non-framework options? (libraries)

Comment: @JohnnyHK Those are for syncing your frontend model with your view. I'm not worried about the view at all. None of that addresses syncing data with a database.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar, what did you go for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Are there any non-framework options?` Yes, javascript and node.js

You can implement the logic described in your questions with pure javascript, it will take much time when compared to using a framework. Meteor already provides this out of the box but you have options like [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org/) that support more databases when compared to Meteor (currently only supports Mongodb).

Maybe you can use Angularjs with Restangular do archive this. On the server you have to implement long polling, assuming that you don't want to use websockets. You can also use [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) to handle the server side logic, it provides realtime updates for all subscribed clients.

Comment: `Yes, javascript and node.js` I've coded this 100 times by now. It's the same thing everytime, I want a library for it! I'm planning on using sailsJS, but I'll still have to do all the frontend ajax manually. Restangular looks cool if I were using angular. Firebase looks interesting.

Comment: Looks like firebase calls this "3-way data binding"

Comment: One question: You mention long polling if we do not want to use websocket. What if we are ok with it? Do you know if sail.js/meteor will allow offline changes and then synchronize?